# How can I fix the css so the content will wrap inside the second div?

Tags: css

I have tried several display settings but nothing seems to work to achieve what I want. Here is my example in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kongakong/asgLo7c7/1/)

Essentially what I want to do is to display an icon and a name, both in `div`, side by side. This is my intended layout:

[image]

However when the name is long, the name-holding div drops to below the first icon div.

[image]

As commented in the jsfiddle code, I have tried float-left and pre-wrap but they do not work for some reason.

How can I make the text wraps inside the second div and stay to the right hand side of the icon div?

Comment: Absolutely position the avatar, relatively position the name with padding-left equal to the width of the avatar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try: `display:table` and `display:table-cell`;

```
<div style="width:200px;position:absolute;display:table">

        <div style="display:table-cell">
            <img src=https://avatar.guim.co.uk/user/12754044>
        </div>
    <!-- 1) float:left to both div does not work. Outer div becomes a line -->
    <!-- 2) float:left to 2nd div only causes name to go outside div -->
    <!-- 3) add pre-wrap No change -->
        <div style="display:table-cell;vertical-align:top">
            I have a very long name
        </div>

</div>
```

And maybe you also need `vertical-align:top` to align the text.

http://jsfiddle.net/z2vdeu6n/1/

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<div style="width:200px;">
    <div style="float:left">
        <img src=https://avatar.guim.co.uk/user/12754044>
    </div>
    <div style="white-space: normal;word-break:break-word;">I have a very long nameI have a very long name</div>
</div>
```

You may not need most of the css.

Demo :http://jsfiddle.net/asgLo7c7/5/

Comment: This is a very clean solution!

Comment: @Anthony Kong: it depends on what you need, if you want to text to be able to flow with the image, this is a very good solution: http://jsfiddle.net/asgLo7c7/15/ . But if you want text and image to be separated, try `display:table` and `display:table-cell`: http://jsfiddle.net/z2vdeu6n/2/

Comment: @Khanh TO generally name doesn't gets longer than the text in the answer. So, you can use this solution. But if you are unsure about the length of name you may go ahead with the display:table method

Answer (score 1):

Try the below answer

```
<div style="width:200px;position:absolute">
<div style="display:inline-block;float:left">
    <img src=https://avatar.guim.co.uk/user/12754044>
</div>
<!-- 1) float:left to both div does not work. Outer div becomes a line -->
<!-- 2) float:left to 2nd div only causes name to go outside div -->
<!-- 3) add pre-wrap No change -->
<div style="position:absolute;left:65px">
    I have a very long name very lonnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnng nane
</div>
```

Comment: @Anthony Kong If the answer is working  click tick mark for all

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer. I think the 'display:table' solution works better for me. Your answer is upvoted nonetheless!

Answer (score -1):

Setting width could solve your problem,

```
<div class='wrap' style="width:200px;position:absolute">
    <div style="display:inline-block;float:left;width: 60px;">
        <img src=https://avatar.guim.co.uk/user/12754044>
    </div>

    <div style="display:inline-block;float:left;white-space: pre-wrap;width: calc( 100% - 60px );">I have a very long name</div>
</div>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maio/asgLo7c7/16/)